# How to find the common parent of two classes in a class hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent-child, sfinae

I have a single inheritance class hierarchy defined as follows :

```
struct A        { using Parent = void;  void fnct() { std::cout << "A\n";   } };
struct AA : A   { using Parent = A;     void fnct() { std::cout << "AA\n";  } };
struct AB : A   { using Parent = A;     void fnct() { std::cout << "AB\n";  } };
struct AAA : AA { using Parent = AA;    void fnct() { std::cout << "AAA\n"; } };
struct AAB : AA { using Parent = AA;    void fnct() { std::cout << "AAB\n"; } };
struct ABA : AB { using Parent = AB;    void fnct() { std::cout << "ABA\n"; } };
struct ABB : AB { using Parent = AB;    void fnct() { std::cout << "ABB\n"; } };
```

Each class in the hierarchy defines an alias `Parent` to its direct parent class, and a member function `void fnct()`.

I needed to define a template function `call_fnct_upto_parent<P,C>(C&)` which, for a given object of class `C` and a given parent class `P` of the class hierarchy, calls all of the member functions `fnct()` from the object type `C` up to the parent type `P`. I implemented this using SFINAE as follows :

```
template<class P, class C>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<P,C>::value,void>::type call_fnct_upto_parent(C& c)
{
    c.fnct();
    static_assert(!std::is_same<typename C::Parent,void>::value, "parent not found");
    call_fnct_upto_parent<P, typename C::Parent>(c);
}

template<class P, class C>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<P,C>::value,void>::type call_fnct_upto_parent(C& c)
{
    c.fnct();
}
```

Function `call_fnct_upto_parent<P,C>(C&)` defined above works as expected as long as `P` is parent of `C`. For example, a call to `call_fnct_upto_parent<A>(aaa)`, where `aaa` is of type `AAA`, results in subsequent calls to `aaa.AAA::fnct()`, `aaa.AA::fnct()` and `aaa.A::fnct()`, resolved at compile time.

Now, I would like to define a template function `call_fnct_upto_common_parent<Ch,Co>(Co&)` which, for a given object of class `Co` and a given class `Ch` of the class hierarchy, calls all of the member functions `fnct()` from the object type `Co` up to the type `P` of the closest common parent to classes `Ch` and `Co`. As an example, a call to `call_fnct_upto_common_parent<AB>(aaa)`, would result in subsequent calls to `aaa.AAA::fnct()`, `aaa.AA::fnct()` and `aaa.A::fnct()`, because class `A` is the closest common parent to classes `AB` and `AAA`.

Can such a function be implemented and how ? A solution with calls resolved at compile time would be preferable, if feasible.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `std::is_base_of` with a similar structure to your existing code:

```
template<class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<U,T>::value,void>::type 
call_fnct_upto_common_parent(U& u)
{
    u.fnct();
    static_assert(!std::is_same<typename U::Parent,void>::value, "parent not found");
    call_fnct_upto_common_parent<T, typename U::Parent>(u);
}

template<class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<U,T>::value,void>::type 
call_fnct_upto_common_parent(U& u)
{
    u.fnct();
}
```

Comment: as simple as that... didn't know `std::is_base_of<>`; works perfectly well, thank you very much.